# Increase Storage of Azure App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-app-service-plans

We are looking into moving a number of websites to Microsoft Azure. We believe the App Service standard tier S1 service will meet most of our needs.

[App Service plan details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3ie0.png)

Unfortunately, it offers a maximum of 50Gb of storage. Is it possible to add storage to the service plan overall? (e.g. the storage will be available to all of the apps on the app service).

I know you can add blob storage to each app individually, but we would prefer to increase the available storage on the service plan as a whole.

Comment: What are you storing?

Comment: @JamesWood We will be hosting content managed websites, some of which have a large collection of images. There will also be cached versions of these images at different resolutions and formats etc.

We could move the media folder to blob storage on a per-site basis but it would be easier to increase the app service storage overall (if that is possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that 50GB is the limit on a standard plan.

> **App Service limits**
>
> Standard; 50GB.
>
> Premium; 500GB.

I suppose this leaves you with *(at least)* the following options.

1. Upgrade your plan to Premium.
2. See if Microsoft will raise your limit.

> **Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints**
>
> If you want to raise the limit or quota above the Default Limit, open
> an online customer support request at no charge. The limits can't be
> raised above the Maximum Limit...If there is no Maximum Limit column, then the resource doesn't have adjustable limits.

3. Find some other solution which removes the need to place data on your App Service. Such as a dedicated Azure storage mechanism, e.g. blobs, CDNs, Redis Cache, SQL, etc.
4. Look into App Service Environment.

> **App Service limits**
>
> The storage limit [of an App Service] is the total content size across
> all apps in the same App Service plan. More storage options are
> available in App Service Environment.
>
> **App Service Environment Storage**
>
> Each ASE is configured with 500 GB of storage. This space is used across all the apps in the ASE.

- [Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits)
- [App Service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits)
- [App Service Environment Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-web-configure-an-app-service-environment#storage)

Answer (score 2):

File system quota for App Service hosted apps is determined by the **aggregate of App Service plans created in the region and resource group**.

You can create one or more standard app service plan which will give you multiples of 50GB  (50GB * x) file system storage. You can decide not to deploy anything in the additional app service plan you created, just use it to increase your storage size. Remember that it should be in the same region and resource group.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks. Does this apply to other resources like RAM too?

Comment: @CageE I doubt it adds up compute resources across ASP